# Building FFTW with debug symbols - problems on port to 64-bit target

Tags: gcc, gdb, 32bit-64bit, fftw

I need to find why fftw is segfaulting, in an application which built OK on 32-bit target with gcc4.0 and now fails on a 64-bit target with gcc4.6.

The fftw configure options:

- --enable-debug
- --enable-debug-malloc
- --enable-debug-alignment

only appear to add internal debug, I was hoping to get somewhere by turning on gdb debug symbols so I can try to trace the cause of the segfault.  Is there an option for gdb debug that I've missed somehow?

Alternatively, is there any other way I should be trying to track down a segfault in fftw?

Comment: the Makefile produced by configure included -g in the CFLAGS, I've changed to -ggdb and now get debug info for gdb.  A null plan is being returned, so that's narrowed down the search.

Comment: The planning flags are all set to 1, so it's returning a null from fftwf_mkapiplan, as it thinks FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY is set, and it has no wisdom loaded.

Comment: And that was because FFTW_FORWARD is defined as -1 in the FFTW library include file, as it always has been.  Not clear why that suddenly caused a problem on the new build, but I don't need it right now anyway as it's implied in real to complex transforms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As noted in my comments above, the answer was to edit the Makefile produced by fftw3's configure to add -ggdb to the CFLAGS.